# Liquibase tried to apply all changeset, even if database is present

Tags: java, mysql, spring, liquibase

I am using `Spring-Liquibase` to perform any migration that is needed on the staging database.

The `applicationContext.xml` looks like

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yahoo.comma"/>
    <bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:liquibase/changelog.xml"/>
        <property name="defaultSchema" value="pryme_dev"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

When I deploy the war file, i see errors in log as

```
INFO 6/11/14 9:32 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 6/11/14 9:32 AM:liquibase: Reading from pryme_dev.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 6/11/14 9:32 AM:liquibase: Reading from pryme_dev.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 6/11/14 9:32 AM:liquibase: Reading from pryme_dev.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 6/11/14 9:32 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::harith: Reading from pryme_dev.DATABASECHANGELOG
SEVERE 6/11/14 9:32 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::harith: Change Set liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::harith failed.  Error: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE pryme_dev.network (id INT NOT NULL, network_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, display_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, active TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL, created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL, updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01' NOT NULL, created_by VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'pryme_user' NULL, updated_by VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'pryme_user' NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_NETWORK PRIMARY KEY (id)): Table 'network' already exists
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE pryme_dev.network (id INT NOT NULL, network_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, display_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, active TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL, created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL, updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01' NOT NULL, created_by VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'pryme_user' NULL, updated_by VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'pryme_user' NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_NETWORK PRIMARY KEY (id)): Table 'network' already exists
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:61)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:106)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1189)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1172)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:352)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:40)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:64)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:181)
    at com.yahoo.comma.persistence.DataSetupTest.liquibaseUpdate(DataSetupTest.java:53)
    at com.yahoo.comma.integration.IT1DataSetup.generateDataSet(IT1DataSetup.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'network' already exists
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:734)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:294)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:54)
    ... 44 more
INFO 6/11/14 9:32 AM:liquibase: liquibase/2014/1-1.xml::05192014.1525::harith: Successfully released change log lock
09:32:14.299 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@3ba0fcf
```

**Questions**
- Why is it applying all the changesets when database is already populated and that the database has `DATABASECHANGELOG` file present?
- How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at the stack trace this isn't so much of liquibase but more the way you have setup your test cases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is often because part of the unique identifier for each changeSet is the path to the changelog file. It looks like it currently sees it as "liquibase/2014/1-1.xml".

If you run `select * from databasechangelog where id='05192014.1525'` what is the path already in the database?

Comment: In my case, somehow `DATABASECHANGELOG` table itself was empty. However, other tables were in tact

Answer (score 7):

Just adding new, more direct info on why the issue happens.

[Liquibase DATABASECHANGELOG Documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog_table.html)

Liquibase uses the DATABASECHANGELOG table to track which changeSets have been ran.

The table tracks each **changeSet as a row**, identified by a **combination of the “id”, “author” and a “filename” column** which stores the path to the changelog file.

Please note that the filename column stores the path to the changelog. This may be an absolute path or a relative path depending on how the changelog was passed to Liquibase. **For best results, it should be a relative path**.

If you move the database, as in the case of migrating, and the filename column contains full paths, Liquibase may not recognize the changeset from the DATABASECHANGELOG table.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add info about what worked for me,

Liquibase was looking in the path relative to the JAR, 'BOOT-INF/classes/db/changelog/sql/' but the problem was that in the db `databasechangelog`, `filename` column had 'db/changelog/sql/' this path.

So I ran the following query on my database to resolve my issue.

`update customer.databasechangelog set filename = replace(filename, 'db/changelog/sql/', 'BOOT-INF/classes/db/changelog/sql/');`

As I'm new to the liquibase, I'm not sure if this approach is correct, but it did solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks so much, this saved me! - For anyone else, the problem i got was that when creating the project .jar, the path wasnt correct. I needed to update the databasechangelog filename column to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to specify the default schema for Liquibase, adding the spring property:

```
spring.liquibase.default-schema=public
```